# Vb.Net CA1822

Tags: vb.net, code-analysis

I ran a Code Analysis and got this message:

> Warning   5   CA1822 :
>   Microsoft.Performance : The 'this'
>   parameter (or 'Me' in Visual Basic) of
>   'MainForm.CheckFileIfFileIsInUse(String)'
>   is never used. Mark the member as
>   static (or Shared in Visual Basic) or
>   use 'this'/'Me' in the method body or
>   at least one property accessor, if
>   appropriate.  D:\WORK\Update\Update\MainForm.vb

I'm not sure I understand it. This is the line it's referring to:

```
Dim testfile As String = thefilename & ".tst"
```

It's saying that it is never used but in the very next line I have this:

```
If IO.File.Exists(testfile) Then
    IO.File.Delete(testfile)
End If
```

So I know it's being used.  I have this same message in two places I don't get why it's saying it's never used.

Help a confused newbie find his way :P

Thanks as usual,
Eroc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simply showing you the first line of the method - the contents of that line is unimportant. The point is that the method doesn't use the `Me` reference anywhere, so you can declare it to be a `Shared` method instead.

In other words, instead of:

```
Sub CheckFileIfFileIsInUse(ByVal thefilename as String)
    Dim testfile As String = thefilename & ".tst"
    If IO.File.Exists(testfile) Then
        IO.File.Delete(testfile)
    End If
End Sub
```

Have:

```
Shared Sub CheckFileIfFileIsInUse(ByVal thefilename as String)
    Dim testfile As String = thefilename & ".tst"
    If IO.File.Exists(testfile) Then
        IO.File.Delete(testfile)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: And then also consider whether this method really still belongs as part of this type or, being shared, could more logically be associated with a different, more generic type

Comment: Everything in this project is within one form including the CheckFileIfFileIsInUse and the sub calling it. I would think that I do not need to make is shared if that is the case correct? Would I not ignore this 'warning' then?

Comment: You don't *have* to make it shared, no - it's just that it doesn't *need* to be an instance method. The suggestion is that you make it a shared method to avoid the *appearance* that it depends on the instance itself.

Comment: Even if this is a single form application? I assume this is for readability/maintainability?  Should I be doing this as a standard then even if it might not be used outside the form?

Answer (score 2):

The message is referring to the entire method `CheckFileIfFileIsInUse`.  It's telling you that nothing in that method is accessing instance members of the class, so you might as well declare the method `Shared`.

```
Shared Sub CheckFileIfFileIsInUse(ByVal thefilename as String)
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare your method CheckFileIfFileIsInUse as shared. The instead of declaring a new instance of the method, just reference it directly.

```
Use This
MyClass.CheckfileIfFileisInUser(filename)
```

Instead of

```
 Dim newclass as Myclass
 newclass.CheckfileIfFileisInUser(filename)
```

Comment: This answer and the accepted answer helped me understand it better. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that you don't need a instance of the class (your form) to use the Method CheckFileIfFileIsInUse